# Listing resources in runnable jar fails when started from network

Tags: java, networking, jar, resources

I have written a java swing application, which has to find its icons from resources. Therefore I want to find any png in a specific folder in the runnable jar file. I do not know before what names will be in there.

To find the png inside the resource folder i use the following code:

```
private List<String> getResourceFolderFileNames(String folder) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    File jarFile = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    System.out.println("Folder to search in: " + folder);
    try {
        if (jarFile.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("This is a jar file dir");
            JarFile file = new JarFile(jarFile);
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = file.entries();
            List<JarEntry> jarEntries = new ArrayList<>();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                jarEntries.add(entries.nextElement());
            }
            System.out.println("Number of entries: " + jarEntries.size());
            for (JarEntry e: jarEntries
                 ) {
                String name = e.getName();
                if (name.matches(".*/" + folder + "/[0-9]+\\.png")) {
                    name = name.split("/")[2];
                    System.out.println("Added name: " + name);
                    names.add(name);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is not a jar file");
            ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            URL url = loader.getResource("resources/" + folder);
            String path = url.getPath();
            for (File f: new File(path).listFiles()
                 ) {
                names.add(f.getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "catch in get Resource folder file names");
    }
    return names;
}
```

The desired behavior of the code is, that it will return a List of Strings which are all the ******.png file names.

The else part does actually not work yet, but the programm never reaches it. This part is for when you start the search within an IDE because it seems to work different there (pointed out it some other questions). It seems like it does fail on the "jarFile.isFile()".

**The Error:**

When I start the exported runnable jar file on a windows or mac it works perfectly fine. It does exactly what it should do. If I start the same runnable jar file from a network folder it does not find the png files.

**Project structure**

This is where my icons  are located

```
--src/
    --resources/
        --iconfolder1
        --iconfolder2
```

If any more informations needed let me now, I will do my best to help you helping me. Thank you very much.

**edit 1:**

Now it works again in the IDE but still does not work on the Network.

br
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually nothing wrong with the code itself.

What happens is, that getLocation returns an URL and so with getPath this is URL encoded. So now when you have spaces in your path they will be encoded with %20. The constructor of File will not decoded this and so can not read the path.

```
File jarFile = new File(URLDecoder.decode(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(), "UTF-8"));
```

So with decoding the String before making new File will perform as expected.